# For Expression with recursive generator

Tags: scala, recursion

In the 3 code variations below, the For Expression produces totally different output. The recursive generator seems to be sourced from real values (A,B,C) but in version2 and version3 of the function below, none of the letters were present in the yield output. What is the reason?

```
def permuteV1(coll:List[Char]) : List[List[Char]] = {
  if (coll.isEmpty) List(List())
  else {
    for {
      pos <- coll.indices.toList
      elem <- permuteV1(coll.filter(_ != coll(pos)))
    } yield coll(pos) :: elem
  }
}
permuteV1("ABC".toList)
//res1: List[List[Char]] = List(List(A, B, C), List(A, C, B), List(B, A, C), List(B, C, A), List(C, A, B), List(C, B, A))


def permuteV2(coll:List[Char]) : List[List[Char]] = {
  if (coll.isEmpty) List(List())
  else {
    for {
      pos <- coll.indices.toList
      elem <- permuteV2(coll.filter(_ != coll(pos)))
    } yield elem
  }
}
permuteV2("ABC".toList)
//res2: List[List[Char]] = List(List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List())


def permuteV3(coll:List[Char]) : List[List[Char]] = {
  if (coll.isEmpty) List(List())
  else {
    for {
      pos <- coll.indices.toList
      elem <- permuteV3(coll.filter(_ != coll(pos)))
    } yield '-' :: elem
  }
}
permuteV3("ABC".toList)
//res3: List[List[Char]] = List(List(-, -, -), List(-, -, -), List(-, -, -), List(-, -, -), List(-, -, -), List(-, -, -))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all three examples `elem` is the empty `List()`.  When you walk through the recursions you'll see it is the only result possible.

In the 1st case you pre-pend a meaningful value to the empty `elem`.  Those values are saved on the stack and collected when the recursion has reached its conclusion and the stack is unwound.

A different way to get the same result: `"ABC".toList.permutations.toList`

Comment: I know about List.permutations. Permutation is used here just for an example to illustrate a recursive generator. Which is the concept I would like to understand. As you suggested, if I walk through the recursion, I don't see elem as List(). Because the generator `coll.filter(_ != coll(pos))` should return nonEmpty values. Example, for `pos=1` `coll.filter(_ != coll(1))` should generate `List('B', 'C')`

Comment: Yes, `coll.filter(_ != coll(1))` **does** generate `List('B', 'C')`, but that list is immediately sent to `permuteVx()`, where `pos` is set to 0 (i.e. 'B') and `List('C')` is sent to `permuteVx()`, where pos is set to 0 ('C') and `List()` is sent to `permuteVx()`, which sends it back.  What `coll.filter(_!=coll(1))` produces is never part of the output.

Comment: Oh cool. But then, for each value of pos (from the 1st generator `coll.indices.toList`) there is a recursion trip for the 2nd generator which ends up as a single value List(). The item count of the resulting collection output by the ForExpr must then be (3 x 1). How come there are exactly 6 values each time?

Comment: The number of results is n! (n-factorial), where n is the number of elements in the original `List`.  At the base level a recursive call is made for every value of `pos` (3 in your example). At the secondary level it's the same, a recursion for every value of `pos` (2 this time). Etc.

Comment: All makes sense now. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the last snippet, because it is kinda more obvious.

The only thing you ever add to the list is '-', so, it would be surprising if the result contained anything else, right?

Now, by a similar reasoning, in the second example, you *never add anything the list at all*, so, the result can only possibly contain an empty list.

The first one works ... well, because it actually does add data to the result :)

Comment: Hi Dima, can you read the comment I wrote below for @jwvh ? Both of you gave the same answer. About permuteV3, `yield` does output `'-' :: elem` and not `'-'` alone as you suggested. Of course, it is obvious, at least to you, that elem is empty. But can you please elaborate a little bit? I see that the generator feeding elem must produce nonEmpty values. How come elem ends up being empty?

Comment: @Polymerase well, let's try to reason about it. If `elem` is _not_ empty,  what characters does it contain, and where did they come from? Someone must have added them to the list, right? The only thing, that's added by your function is '-'. Where else do you expect the content could come from?